# svg not spinning properly

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a svg file and I'm trying to apply spinning animation (similar like loaders/spinners),  however the rotating radius is too big and I can't seem to control it.
CSS:

```
.image {
     -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
     animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
.image2 {
    -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1s linear infinite;    
}

    @-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

The svg file contains two paths where I add the spin class separately because I need different spinning speeds for both paths.

Here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f0cn4x1k/

Any help is useful,

Comment: Take a look at [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is incorrect.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hy5t1Laz/

Change your CSS to this:

```
.image
{
   -webkit-animation: spin 4s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 4s infinite  linear;
   animation: spin 4s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
  from {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {-o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes spin{
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much works perfectly.